# Filter dataframe based on column names and their content

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe :

```
+-----+----------+---------+
|num  |Timestamp |frequency|
+-----+----------+---------+
|20.0 |1632899456|4        |
|20.0 |1632901256|4        |
|20.0 |1632901796|4        |
|20.0 |1632899155|4        |
|10.0 |1632901743|2        |
|10.0 |1632899933|2        |
|91.0 |1632899756|3        |
|32.0 |1632900776|6        |
|41.0 |1632900176|1        |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

I want to filter it using the content of this map :

```
val filter : Map[String, Seq[String]] = Map("num"-> Seq("20.0", "41.0"), "frequency" -> Seq("6"))
```

The new dataframe would be like this :

```
+-----+----------+---------+
|num  |Timestamp |frequency|
+-----+----------+---------+
|20.0 |1632899456|4        |
|20.0 |1632901256|4        |
|20.0 |1632901796|4        |
|20.0 |1632899155|4        |
|32.0 |1632900776|6        |
|41.0 |1632900176|1        |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

I am using Spark version 3.0.2 and SQLContext, with scala language.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I guess you want to filter records by the predicates (num is 20.0 or 41.0) or (frequency is 6), right?

Comment: Yes, it would be the predicates :  (num is 20.0 or 41.0) or (frequency is 6)

Comment: If your predicates is fixed, a very straitforward way is `df.filter($ "num" === "20.0" || $"num" === "41.0" || $"frequency" === "6")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter with `isin` function

```
val filter: Map[String, Seq[String]] = Map("num" -> Seq("20.0", "41.0"), "frequency" -> Seq("6"))

df.filter(($"num" isin (filter("num"):_*)) or
  ($"frequency" isin (filter("frequency"):_*)))
  .show(false)
```

If you have map which matches the column name then you can use

```
val filterQuery = filter.map(rec => col(rec._1) isin(rec._2:_*)).reduce(_ or _)

df.filter(filterQuery).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+----------+---------+
|num |Timestamp |frequency|
+----+----------+---------+
|20.0|1632899456|4        |
|20.0|1632901256|4        |
|20.0|1632901796|4        |
|20.0|1632899155|4        |
|32.0|1632900776|6        |
|41.0|1632900176|1        |
+----+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Is there any way to iterate over the keys of the map, instead of calling them one by one ?

Comment: if column name and key of map are matched then you can do iterate it

Answer (score 0):

You can build a String query with the map as origin as follows:

```
val filterQuery = filter
                   .map{case (k,v) => v.map(v1 => (k,v1))}
                   .flatten
                   .map{ case (k,v) => s"$k = $v" }
                   .mkString(" or ")

df.filter(filterQuery)
```

Is not elegant though